# Content loaded with GET requests in a SPA takes a moment to appear on page which makes the transition ugly. Any way to smooth things out?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

At the end of they day, making the GET request takes time and I can't expect to receive the content instantly, however, I am wondering if there are any ways to make the transition from one page to another less eye poking.

Currently when I load the page, first I see an empty page first, then the images with smallest size load and then the rest of the images with average size load. This makes the layout go wild until everything has loaded ( which obviously happens in a blink of an eye, but you still see it ).

Should I put something like a loading screen which would play until everything has been loaded? Are there any other methods of smoothing things out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Level 1 - Don't rely on the actual image size for layout. Use CSS (or height and width attributes) to define dimensions of image tags. This will help with layout getting scrambled.

Level 2 - If you want to see placeholders, try using CSS to give img tags a background-color.

Level 3 - If you are still concerned about overall effect, you can use CSS to hide the entire page and then transition in once page load is complete. For this, you would need to add JS to listen for load complete event and then toggle a CSS class to reveal the content.

**jquery/js**

```
  $(window).load(function() {
    $("body").removeClass("loading");
  });
```

**html**

```
  <body class="loading">...</body>
```

**css**

```
  body {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .5s;
  }

  body.loading {
    opacity: 0;
  }
```